# I passed a struct to a function and called the variables inside a function from struct but it still returns 0

Tags: function, structure, complex-numbers

I am trying to add up the numbers but it prints out 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct kmplx{
    float real;
    float im;
};

float zbroj(struct kmplx k){
    k.real = 5;
    k.im = 1;
    float zbr = k.real + k.im;
    return zbr;
}
float umn(struct kmplx k){
    float prod = k.real * k.im;
    return prod;
}

int main(){
    struct kmplx k;
    printf("%d\n", zbroj(k));
    printf("%d", umn(k));
}
```

I tried to call the variables from struct in main but same result happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we pass a struct to a function, it'll pass a copy of it. So most of the cases, we pass using a pointer or reference.
And because of it, after zbroj(k) runs, k variable in the main function is still the same as before because you have written data to copy of it.
As a result, umn(k) returns 0 (in some cases, it could be an unexpected number).

In your case, you need to define function as following.

```
float zbroj(struct kmplx& k) {
...
}
```

PS. %d is for integer and you need to use %f for float.

```
printf("%f\n", zbroj(k));
```

Comment: Ok, so I only put k.real and k.im in main and I changed %d to %f. I left the parameters as it was before and it gave me a good result. Thanks.

Comment: Since the question is about C, it should use the 'c' tag. Plus the code is more readable if you format the code for C using 'c'  after the triple back tick.